# slider overlaping on collapsed icon on navigation bootstrap 4 (on mobile)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-lg navbar-light bg-faded justify-      content-center">
 <div class="container ">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"   aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon m-auto"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active mt-5">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)   </span></a>
     </li>
    <li class="nav-item mt-5">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mt-5">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="_images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active mt-5">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item mt-5">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
     <li class="nav-item mt-5">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
```

this is my navigation bootstrap code i used for my navigation

```
    <header>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class=" carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('_images/Slider_1.jpg')">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>First Slide</h3>
                    <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('_images/Slider_2.jpg')">

                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>Second Slide</h3>
                    <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('_images/Slider_3.jpg')">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>Third Slide</h3>
                    <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

i am having problem when i view my website on mobile at collapsed navigation stage slider over lap icon of collapsed button which hide that i am new with bootstrap so anyone have idea how to resolve this issue. sorry for bad english

Comment: can you create online demo for same thing or live url

Comment: www.kamran.tahirhassan.com view it on mobiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here we go,

remove class `justify-content-center` from `nav` tag in html this is causing lot of problems, and apply below css this will fix your css issues

```
.navbar{
  min-height: 60px;
}
.navbar .container{
  width: 100%;
}
```

see [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fet1Q.png)